# Reverse String Linked List Recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I would like to first create a linked list with strings from the user (until the user inputs a full-stop), then reverse it recursively and then print the new list.
The program below is what I got so far: it is compiling but only displays the last word. I reckon that at some point I am assigning a new string to the memory location of one of the previous ones. 
I am relatively new to C++ and can't think of the moment when I went wrong.
Any comments or hints will be highly appreciated!
Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//create a node that reads a string and points to next one
struct Node
{
    string word;
    Node * next;
};

//create current and temporary pointers for Node
Node * current;
Node * temp;

//function to reverse Node
void Reverse(struct Node * p, Node * hdr)
{
    if (p->next == NULL)
    {
        hdr = p;
        return;
    }
    Reverse(p->next, hdr);
    struct Node * q = p->next;
    q->next = p;
    p->next = NULL;
    return;
    }

//function to print linked list
void print(Node * header)
{
    cout << "The reversed linked list is: " << endl;
    Node * ptr = header;
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        cout << ptr->word << " ";
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    //Ask user to input keyboard strings
    cout << "Please insert strings seperated by white spaces (isolated    full-stop to finish): " << endl;
    string input;

    //create head pointer
    Node * head = new Node;
    head->next = NULL;

    //create loop to read words and insert them into linked list
    while(true)
    {
        cin >> input;
        if (input == ".")
            break;
        current = new Node;
        current->word = input;
        current->next = head->next;
        head->next = current;
    }

    //get and output reversed linked list
    Reverse(current, head);
    print(head);
    cout << " ." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems that you already reverse your list when you build the linked list. It will be easier to handle this, if you keep track of both the head and tail of the list (insert at tail, keep the header pointing at the first element)

Comment: So you mean my mistake is when building the linked list in the first place?
How can I best keep the header constantly pointing at the first input (outside the loop) while getting new inputs (inside the loop)?
Thank you Stefan!

Comment: I think also the Reverse function has a problem. You correctly run through the list but I think you discard the information, when you return. I think the best way to analyse this to draw the list on paper, using an example with 3 nodes. As for the header, you can make a new node before the loop, then fill in the information in the loop, then make the next node, still in the loop

Comment: Using recursion for this kind of task is a mistake -- it only adds complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
void recursiveReverse(struct node** head_ref)
{
    struct node* first;
    struct node* rest;

    /* empty list */
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
       return;   

    /* suppose first = {1, 2, 3}, rest = {2, 3} */
    first = *head_ref;  
    rest  = first->next;

    /* List has only one node */
    if (rest == NULL)
       return;   

    /* reverse the rest list and put the first element at the end */
    recursiveReverse(&rest);
    first->next->next  = first;  

    /* tricky step -- see the diagram */
    first->next  = NULL;          

    /* fix the head pointer */
    *head_ref = rest;              
}
```

Refer http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-function-to-reverse-the-nodes-of-a-linked-list/

Comment: If you wish to reverse a linked list recursively you'll have to use a double pointer.

Comment: So if I later use the recursiveReverse function in the main function, which parameter can I insert? I tried it with "head" but it is not compatible.

Comment: Send &head. Please up vote the answer if it helped you :)